# "Compenent" elements seen as "ProductDocument" in CATIA VBA

Tags: vba, catia

I have a problem. I can import feature types in catia vba with the following codes

```
 Set document1 = CATIA.Documents.Item("Product1.CATProduct")
 Set products1 = document1.Product.Products

 For i = 1 To products1.Count

    MsgBox TypeName(products1.Item(i).ReferenceProduct.Parent)

 Next i
```

but it also shows "Compenent" elements as "ProductDocument". If component is, I want to make a separate operation.

How can I find out that an element is a "Component" ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmhyX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution

```
For Each prd In products1
  If prd.ReferenceProduct.Parent.Product.PartNumber <> prd.PartNumber Then
   '... this is a component
  End If
Next
```